# GTA V won't load online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, rockstar-games-social-club

I've been playing GTA V online for a while after I installed the game I took it out. When I put in GTA V after playing something else it took me to story mode. I tried loading GTA online, but it says I need to be connected to PSN, which I am. I've  tried uninstalling the game and update then reinstalling and I also tried restarting my ps3 and my Wi-Fi modem but nothing worked. Could there be something  wrong with the Rockstar servers or is it my ps3?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with steam version on my laptop. When I connected to another WiFi it worked without any error. But when I connected back to the first WiFi it would give the same error. So I followed these steps:

1. Go to “cmd” and run as administrator.
2. Than copy all this one by one
3. `ipconfig /flushdns`         : (clear dns cache)
4. `nbtstat –RR`                : (release and refesh NetBIOS names)
5. `netsh int ip reset`         : (reset ip settings)
6. `netsh winsock reset`        : (ResetWinsock Catalog)
7. Finally restart your computer.

**I know you have ps3 but try to connect to another WiFi.**

Answer (score -3):

I would try to use a Ethernet cable that connects straightly into your ps3, for better connection to online services and would probably fix your issue.